# How to reset the last operation in MeshLab

Tags: meshlab

Is there any way to reset an operation in MeshLab (previous button). The "reload" option will only recall the last saved state of the model. do i need to save after each operation?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately right now there is no such feature in meshlab (no CTRL+Z).
It is a very highly demanded request in meshlab, but right now the complexity of its codebase does not allow to easily implement it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "undo" in Meshlab. You can approximate this functionality by saving your work frequently.